# Is it possible to bring only the orders of that user with Jwt token?

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I have a website where my customers can order. The customer receives a jwt token after logging in. If he wants to check his past orders, all orders are returning here, I have to do ten hundred filtering and it is not safe. Can I send a jwt token to order find instead and get only the data belonging to that jwt token?

ex: //
The user logs in.

Jwt token arrives.

The user wants to see the previous orders.

It goes into my old orders.

A request is made to the order parameter.

response :

[
{
"id": ,
"status":,
"total": ,
"checkout_session": "",
"sozlesme":,
"date": "",
"name": "",
"surname": "",
"company": "",
"adress": "",
"town": "",
"state": "",
"postcode": "",
"country": "",
"pnumber": "",
"email": "",
"payment_type": "",
"created_at": "",
"updated_at": "",
"product": ,
"users_permissions_user":,
"user":
},
{"id": ,
"status":,
"total": ,
"checkout_session": "",
"sozlesme":,
"date": "",
"name": "",
"surname": "",
"company": "",
"adress": "",
"town": "",
"state": "",
"postcode": "",
"country": "",
"pnumber": "",
"email": "",
"payment_type": "",
"created_at": "",
"updated_at": "",
"user":
"product": {}
},
"users_permissions_user":,
"user": {}
}
]

It is coming in orders that do not belong to the users given so far.

I want to make jwt tokens when sending requests to orders.

Whichever user the Jwt token matches, only the one that belongs to it should transform.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and where the specific challenge is within that simplified code to reproduce your issue IN the question.

Comment: Your question is very vague and general, you should provide more details. However, the purpose of a JWT is to identify a user, you have to decode it and then find the orders that belong to the user (assuming your data is modeled like that, if you provided information we could know...)

Comment: *ten hundred filtering and it's not safe* this part is absolutely unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Post Order request you will have to pass

> user: id

of the User such that the order is linked to the user.
In the Get Order Requst

> http://localhost:1337/order?user=id

Otherwise you can add a policy to the get method isOwner policy in the route.json file. Refer https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/is-owner.html